# Learning resources for first time sharepoint end user?

Tags: user, learning

A new end user has started using your sharepoint site. They have never used sharepoint before. What do you recommend they start read/watch/listen to? What is the best resource for first time sharepoint users?

Answer (score 2):

For online video training I recommend [Pluralsight](http://www.pluralsight.com). The have recently added lots of "end user" courses. Also a great resource for developers and administrators.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you start off with the following free resources:

- [SharePoint Learning Kit](http://slk.codeplex.com/)
- [Productivity Hub 2010 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28178&hash=yuDTYYZHmudXHg2PgNMmitPYBOf96sX1z3YzbZFqVnO0qQgvl00dn3bCQ/CqJgcvtJ/g4a5vhLe1OMKG3UNraQ==)
  (versions for other SP versions are also available; do a search on microsoft.com)

If those do not help your end users, which I thought it, then go with the paid subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

For online video training, I recommend lynda.com.  Very inexpensive monthly subscriptions, and most end users should be able to get through the training videos before one month is complete.  They offer a lot of training, but just look them up and enter "sharePoint" and you'll see the options for both end users or administrators.  I am a SharePoint consultant, and I use these videos with my clients.